# How to convert from a INT value HHMMSS to TimeSpan using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating an application in PowerShell to reschedule the existing jobs in a SQL Server instance. So I have to get the `active_start_time` value from the `sysschules` table. The time value is formatted as `INT` HHMMSS on a 24-hour clock.

As I am using the JobSchedule class (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobSchedule) in my PowerShell application, I need to convert from time value in `INT` to a TimeSpan value in order add to `ActiveStartTimeOfDay` property.

**Example:**

Original data: `[INT]` active_start_time = 10500

Expected data: `[TimeSpan]` ActiveStartTimeOfDay = 01h 05 min 00s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As FoxDeploy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493290/712649), treat the input number as a string!

First, you'll want to use [`String.PadLeft()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1) to zero-pad the number:

```bsh
$active_start_time = 10500
$start_timestamp = "$active_start_time".PadLeft(6, '0') # "010500"
```

Now that we have a "timestamp" of sorts, `[timespan]` has a [`ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) method we can use to parse any format:

```bsh
$start_timespan = [timespan]::ParseExact($start_timestamp, 'hhmmss', $null)
```

Comment: Thank you, Mathias!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by taking your input `int` and treating it like a string.  Doing that lets us call `ToCharArray()` which does this.

```
$myString = "Hi!"
$myString.ToCharArray()
H
i
!
```

Once it's in a char array, we can select out the positions of the characters we want by specifying its index, starting with zero, like this:

```
PS> $myString.ToCharArray()[0] #get's the first
H
```

Applying that to your scenario, we do the same to select only the numbers we want and tuck them into variables to call on later.  With that, we can easily build a new `[TimeSpan]` object.

```
$inputInt = 121515
$hours= $inputInt.ToString().ToCharArray()[0..1] -join ''
$mins= $inputInt.ToString().ToCharArray()[2..3] -join ''
$secs = $inputInt.ToString().ToCharArray()[4..5] -join ''

$hours,$mins,$secs -join ":"
Output> 12:15:15
```

There are a lot of options to make a new `[TimeSpan]`, we can see our choices by typing the static class name and method, and seeing what comes up.

```
PS> [timespan]::new

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                             
-------------------                                                                                                             
timespan new(long ticks)                                                                                                        
timespan new(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)                                                                               
timespan new(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)                                                                     
timespan new(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
```

That second one looks promising...

```
$newTimeSpan = [TimeSpan]::new($hours,$mins,$secs)
$newTimeSpan
```

This should get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a need to use `.ToCharArray()`. Seems like you can just use the `[0..1]` index syntax on a string.

Comment: I believe he specified his input was an int, I think.

Comment: Hi FoxDeploy, thanks for answering that. But I think that will break when the input length is less than 6 digit. For example, $inputInt = 5 then I need a TimeSpan like 00:00:05.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Yes, he said it was an int. But you are calling `.ToString()` to get a string and then `.ToCharArray()` on that string (three times). Seems like you could ditch the `.ToCharArray()` since it's not serving any purpose.